# Spring security custom login form not invoked

Tags: security, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, configuration

I am trying to configure spring MVC web application to use custom login form for authentication using annotations. My problem is that custom login form is never opened, but instead of it I always get standard spring security login form.

I have defined the following `SecurityConfiguration` class:

```
package com.test.spring.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()  
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .usernameParameter("user_login")
                .passwordParameter("user_password")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login?time=1")
                .maximumSessions(10);
    }

}
```

And `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class:

```
package com.test.spring.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Also I created custom login form as `login.html` so I assumed that the configuration would load my `login.html` file instead standard spring security login form.

Whatever I do, I always get the standard login form:

[image]

I have also configured my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
```

It seems that my security configuration wasn't loaded at all.

Where is the problem?

Comment: just to test what you have have when you access /spring/login.html

Comment: Follow this, may be you missied configuration of controller with URL http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

Comment: /spring/login.html is redirected back to /spring/login with standard login form

Comment: I was also following the spring security guide but it doesn't help to resolve my problem...still trying to figure out what is wrong

Comment: did you do this registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

Comment: it seems your controller is not registered, try with a breakpoint or logs if you are hitting your controller..

Comment: Yes I have the following in my WebAppConfiguration: @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

Comment: it seems that my security configuration is completely ignored, because if I allow every request without authentication, then I still get standard login form to authenticate...

Comment: are you hitting your controller code ? did you config InternalResourceViewResolver to use .html or .jsp?

Comment: Hmm it can be add @Configuration on SecurityConfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

The solution is really simple. My security configuration wasn't loaded at all because `SecurityConfiguration` class must extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

After that, configuration was loaded and everything is working as expected.

So, instead

```
public class SecurityConfiguration
```

There should be

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```